# Sending email alerts for a specific location

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, google-maps, cron

On the webpage there is a google map where the user can change the location to one that he is interested in and sign up for alerts of new jobs by pressing a button. The location of interest saved will be defined by the bounds of the google map. Whenever a new job appears within that bound, an email alert will be sent to that user based on a frequency chosen by him (every hour or every day).

**Problem**: I am confused on how I should process all the alerts for all users.

Currently I am thinking of using a cron job for a table with all the `lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, user_id` for hourly alerts that runs every hour, and another cron job for another table for daily alerts that runs once a day say 9pm. The cron job will loop through all the individual user's lat, lng pairs that define the google map bounds, and query the main `jobs` database for any jobs with posting timestamp within 1hr (or 1 day). If there is, an email alert will be sent.

This seems like a lot of work for the server, especially when there are 5000 user's location preferences and 1,000,000 jobs in the database. (30-ish mins to finish the cronjob?) I am stuck here and would like your opinions.

Comment: How are the alerts added to the system? I guess that's key to finding the best way to work with the data

Comment: Similar to this (http://www.crimemapping.com/subscriptions/Subscribe.aspx). THe user moves the map around to find a spot that he likes and press a button. The google map bounds coordinates are then saved to the tables for either hourly or daily alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching everything every time the cron runs (assuming I'm reading correctly that that's what you're doing), I'd consider performing that check when the alert is added:

Alert added to the system. System checks for any matching boundaries, if any are found then for each match store that info into a separate table. Stick two extra columns in this new table, one for hourly sending, one for daily.

On the hourly check, just send those where the hourly flag hasn't yet been applied, and for the daily, send those where the daily flag hasn't been set.

Then delete any where both have been set afterwards.

Doing it this way, you'll be breaking up the work to be done from one massive check on each cron job (All alerts, all boundaries), to one smaller check for each alert (One alert, all boundaries).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can probably create two cron with this frequency

- by hour.
- by day.

(or any frequency you like)

Rather than processing all the alerts for all users, why not when user subscribed to a location, in your php codeigniter, create a task file with details of this job. Example, user_id, location(coordinate), frequency. The exact detail for this task file depend
in your situation and you will need to analyze into your system. Then place this task file to a directory.

Then based on the frequency you specified above, create a general php script to be called in the frequency. This script will loop through the directories, process the task file and send out email. This way, you will not worry to scan the whole database. There is also minor details like remove, update, delete task file but this is entirely implementation related.

Side note, probably this is irrevent since you tag this question with php but just if you would like to know, *quartz* do exactly what you want but it is in Java though. You can find out [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/) if you want.